# Unable to install Xcode

Tags: xcode

On the App Store, I searched for Xcode and clicked on 'Get' >> 'Install' then a pop up comes for me to login to my Apple iD.

When I do so, I click on 'Get' again and on 'Install' again and then the whole cycle repeats with the Apple id login.

I have plenty of disk space on my machine.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it only Xcode or do other applications have the same problem?

Comment: I downloaded CCleaner and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: Hi Has, welcome to Ask Different. Have you installed CCleaner from the Mac App Store? I ask because, in my country (Switzerland), it is not available.

Comment: Hi Jaume, I just googled it and downloaded the dmg file and installed it :)

Comment: @Has Have you tried the first troubleshoots, sign out and in? Also in App Store preferences, set passwords demand to 15 minutes. and save for free ones. also, [edit] to update the question about new findings.

Comment: Still no luck :(